# Deleting partitions without losing data

Tags: mount, backup, data

**Case 1:**

Let's say I `mount /dev/sda3 /var`
and this entry is not in `/etc/fstab`.
After unmounting `/var`, if `/dev/sda3` is an unused partition (no entries in the fstab), if I delete it I will not lose any data, correct?

**Case 2:**

Again let's `mount /dev/sda3 /var`, however this time `/dev/sda3` has a mount point at `/usr` in `/etc/fstab` - currently not mounted. If I umount /var, and now delete `/dev/sda3` - noting that it is NOT mounted currently will I lose the data on /usr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1:  Yes, you will lose whatever went into `/var` while `/dev/sda3` was mounted there.  Since various system services and other applications use that directory for permanent storage, it is probably a bad idea to either unmount it or delete the contents.

Case 2:  You will not lose anything currently in `/usr`, but the system will probably not work as soon as you arbitrarily mount something on it.  If that partition contains your real `/usr`, it should be mounted there at boot and never removed.  If that partition does not contain your real `/usr`, it should **never** be mounted there.

To make this clear: Fooling around by mounting different partitions arbitrarily on `/var` and/or `/usr` is *stupid*, do not do it.

Comment: Okay - there's something I forgot to add. By default, /dev/sda1 is mounted on /, and /var is included under /. 
So if I umount /var and delete /dev/sda3, doesn't that mean that the existing files are still under /dev/sda1?
Are you trying to say that if I performed any **additional** operations on /var while it was mounted under /dev/sda3 then those changes would be lost?

Comment: If you mount something on a directory that contains information, that information becomes unavailable, and whatever is in the mounted partition effectively replaces it.  So, if you had `/var` as part of a single partition mounted on `/`, then you mounted `/dev/sda3` on it, whatever is in `sda3` is now your `/var`.  When you unmount it, `/var` will be exactly the same as it was **before** you mounted `sda3` there. If you then delete `sda3`, you will lose anything put there while it was mounted.

Comment: so in light of this, it would be a very bad idea to arbitrarily mount 'significant directories' to partitions, because **some** data may be written to those partitions, and if the partition was remounted on another partition, the data would be spread across two partitions, right?

Comment: Yeah, you'd basically be moving information to where it can't be found.  In the case of `/var`, it might not be immediately apparent that there are problems, but moving `/usr` will be a complete disaster.   Presuming you have a motive for wanting to do stuff like this, the best idea is to ask specifically about it *and* explain the motivation, because there may be a much simpler solution to whatever your problem is.